# WCF 4.0 new enhancements over WCF 3.5

Tags: .net, wcf

What are the new enhancements in WCF 4.0 and how easy would it be to upgrade existing WCF services to 4.0?

Comment: See the link below http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx hope that will help.

Answer (score 2):

- Simplified configuration
- Standard endpoints
- IIS hosting without an SVC file
- Discovery
- Routing service (previously included with Dublin)
- REST caching and help page
- Workflow services
- Non-destructive queue receive
- Simple byte stream encoding
- ETW tracing